# Exibir HTML diferente em Web App

Tags: html, css, aplicação-web, app

Tenho um site responsivo, porém preciso que ele seja exibido de forma diferente dentro de um iframe de webapp (sem menu de navegação, sem rodapé, por exemplo). Como faço para carregar um css diferente, ou ocultar elementos, se o conteúdo for carregado dentro do aplicativo/iframe? (lembrando que a versão responsiva no navegador continuará do jeito que está).

Obrigado.

Comment: Está usando algum framework?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem. O seu site já está responsivo para dispositivos mobiles, e você quer que carregue outro css quando for acessado pelos mesmos? Teria como explicar melhor?

Comment: Exato. Coisas do meu patrão. Ele quer que, mesmo com o site sendo responsivo, seja desenvolvido um aplicativo (que carrega o mesmo site/endereço, porém sem alguns elementos, como o cabeçalho e o rodapé...) -  Eu consegui já carregar outro CSS detectando se a página for aberta em um frame, mas não funcionou.  **Preciso que haja como detectar se o site está sendo acessado pelo navegador ou por um aplicativo.**

Comment: Só para dar feedback de como resolvi:
Media query não funcionaria, pois iria alterar também a visualização fora do aplicativo.

O que fiz foi mandar o aplicativo abrir um link diferente, no caso um php que faria a ponte criando uma session, e dentro da página em questão carregar esta session e, carregando 2 estilos diferentes via javascript: 1) se tivesse uma session criada ou 2) sem session criada.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o recurso `media query` possa te ajudar.

O código abaixo informa que os elementos com a classe `.only-webapp` terão `display:none` enquanto a largura estiver abaixo de 400px.

```
@media(max-width: 400px){
    .only-webapp{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

[Código no js Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/urrqwkrp/1/)